How do I remove the amount of space between different boxplots and the division through facet_grid()

I want to remove unnecessary space between the y axis and the boxplots and between the two groupings of boxplots (that I created through facet_grid() ).
Here is what I am currently working with:
kazakh_dor |>
  ggplot(aes(x = CPosWord, y = ClengthMS, fill = TargetC)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5,
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  ylim(c(50, 250)) +
  facet_grid( ~ Vfront) +
  labs(x = "Word position", y = "Duration (ms)") +
  ggtitle("Onsets") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11, angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "right",
    legend.direction = "vertical",
    legend.key.width = unit(2, "line"),
    legend.key.height = unit(1.5, "line"),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0.5, "line"),
    legend.spacing.y = unit(0.5, "line"),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", size = 0.0, linetype = "solid"))

I did try changing the dimensions when I export but that just makes the boxplots skinnier, which I don't want. I honestly don't know the key words to get hits that will answer my question.

We can't reproduce your plot because you haven't given us data. Please provide a reproducible example.

I'm not sure I got your question, but here it goes anyway!
You can modify or eliminate the horizontal spacing between two facets of a plot by changing panel.spacing.x:
library(ggplot2)
iris |> 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(~Species) +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "mm"))


If you want to remove the empty space inside the plot, then add scales = "free_x" to facet_grid:
iris |> 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(~Species, scales = "free_x")



I tried both of your suggestions but they didn't work. I do want to keep the horizontal spacing between two facets the way they are. In your second suggestion, do you notice how little space there is between the boxplot and the edge of the facet (or between boxplot and your y axis scale) .  I want to reduce this space in my boxplots. Do you know how to do that?

You can change that spacing by modifying the horizontal axis, using the expand argument on scale_x_discrete() or similar. It is usually a multiplier. For example, using facet_grid(~Species, scales = "free_x") +  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(.3)) I get a plot like my second one but with a little more space on the sides.
